# React-redux-router migrate to connect-react-router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I build the project from https://github.com/briancappello/flask-react-spa
and try to upgrade the dependencies .

Then i got this error. 
I follow the connect-react-router guide setting , then this error happened.
This error happened when create reducer ,
when initial reducer the method pass undefind ibj to reducer method 
then history's createHref need get pathname from this obj 
and this error happen...

Anyone can gave some advise?  Maybe is dependency issue ?

error stack

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
>       at createPath (history.js:70)
>       at createHref (history.js:366)
>       at eval (redux.js:361)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at assertReducerShape (redux.js:359)
>       at combineReducers (redux.js:422)
>       at createReducer (reducers.js?9c0a:11)
>       at configureStore (configureStore.js?2ddb:35)
>       at Module.eval (index.js?7df2:24)
>       at eval (index.js:109)

reducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import formReducer from 'redux-form/es/reducer'

import { loadingBarReducer } from 'react-redux-loading-bar'

import securityReducer from 'security/reducer'
import flashReducer from 'site/reducers/flash'


const createReducer = (injectedReducers) => combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(injectedReducers),
    security: securityReducer,
    flash: flashReducer,
    form: formReducer,
    loadingBar: loadingBarReducer,

    ...injectedReducers,
})
export default createReducer
```

configureStore.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import { loadingBarMiddleware } from 'react-redux-loading-bar'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import createReducer from 'reducers'
import getSagas from 'sagas'
import { flashClearMiddleware } from 'site/middleware/flash'

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hasWindowObject = typeof window === 'object'

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

export default function configureStore(initialState, history) {
  const middlewares = [
    sagaMiddleware,
    routerMiddleware(history),
    loadingBarMiddleware({ promiseTypeSuffixes: ['REQUEST', 'FULFILL'] }),
    flashClearMiddleware,
  ]

  const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
  ]

  const composeEnhancers =
    isDev && hasWindowObject && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
      ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
      : compose
  const store = createStore(
    createReducer(history),
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(...enhancers)
  )

  // extensions
  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run
  store.injectedReducers = {}
  store.injectedSagas = {}

  let runningSagas = sagaMiddleware.run(function *() {
    yield getSagas()
  })

  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
      const nextCreateReducer = require('./reducers').default
      store.replaceReducer(connectRouter(history)(nextCreateReducer(store.injectedReducers)))
    })

    module.hot.accept('./sagas', () => {
      const nextGetSagas = require('./sagas').default
      runningSagas.cancel()
      runningSagas.done.then(() => {
        runningSagas = sagaMiddleware.run(function *() {
          yield nextGetSagas()
        })
      })
    })
  }

  return store
}
```

here is my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.4.3",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "acorn": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "chalk": "2.4.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.8.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "date-fns": "^2.11.0",
    "fontfaceobserver": "2.1.0",
    "history": "4.9.0",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "3.3.0",
    "immer": "3.0.0",
    "immutable": "^3.8.2",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "invariant": "2.2.4",
    "ip": "1.1.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "path-to-regexp": "^6.1.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "query-string": "^6.11.1",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-bulma-components": "^3.2.0",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-helmet": "6.0.0-beta",
    "react-highlight": "^0.12.0",
    "react-intl": "2.8.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-redux-loading-bar": "^4.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.0.0",
    "react-svg": "^11.0.14",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-form": "^8.2.3",
    "redux-saga": "1.0.2",
    "reselect": "4.0.0",
    "sanitize.css": "8.0.0",
    "seamless-immutable": "^7.1.4",
    "styled-components": "4.2.0",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2",
    "warning": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.23",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "3.1.3",
    "canvas": "^2.6.1",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "5.0.2",
    "compare-versions": "3.4.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0",
    "coveralls": "3.0.3",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "13.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-http-proxy": "^1.6.0",
    "fibers": "^4.0.2",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "4.6.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.8.0",
    "jest-cli": "24.7.1",
    "jest-dom": "3.1.3",
    "jest-styled-components": "^6.3.4",
    "jsdom": "^16.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "lint-staged": "8.1.5",
    "ngrok": "3.1.1",
    "node-plop": "0.18.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "offline-plugin": "5.0.6",
    "plop": "2.3.0",
    "pre-commit": "1.2.2",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "0.2.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.20",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "react-testing-library": "6.1.2",
    "redbox-react": "^1.6.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "sass": "^1.26.3",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "shelljs": "0.8.3",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "stylelint": "10.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "2.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "1.6.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "2.3.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.2.3",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.1",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.6.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.24.3",
    "webpack-pwa-manifest": "^4.2.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "3.0.0"
  }
```

index.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill'

// this must come before everything else otherwise style cascading doesn't work as expected
import 'main.scss'

import { AppContainer as HotReloadContainer } from 'react-hot-loader'
import { areComponentsEqual } from 'react-hot-loader';
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history'

import configureStore from 'configureStore'
import App from 'components/App'
import { login } from 'security/actions'
import { flashInfo } from 'site/actions'
import SecurityApi from 'security/api'
import { storage } from 'utils'


const APP_MOUNT_POINT = document.getElementById('app')

const initialState = {}
const history = createBrowserHistory()
const store = configureStore(initialState, history)

const renderRootComponent = (Component) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <HotReloadContainer>
      <Component store={store} history={history} />
    </HotReloadContainer>,
    APP_MOUNT_POINT
  )
}

const token = storage.getToken()
store.dispatch(login.request())
SecurityApi.checkAuthToken(token)
  .then(({ user }) => {
    store.dispatch(login.success({ token, user }))
  })
  .catch(() => {
    store.dispatch(login.failure())
  })
  .then(() => {
    store.dispatch(login.fulfill())
    renderRootComponent(App)
    const isAuthenticated = store.getState().security.isAuthenticated
    const alreadyHasFlash = store.getState().flash.visible
    if (isAuthenticated && !alreadyHasFlash) {
      store.dispatch(flashInfo('Welcome back!'))
    }
  })

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/App.js', () => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(APP_MOUNT_POINT)
    const NextApp = App.default
      areComponentsEqual(NextApp)
    renderRootComponent(NextApp)
  })
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import  { history } from './index'
import { NavBar, ProgressBar } from 'components'
import { SITE_NAME, COPYRIGHT } from 'config'
import Routes from 'routes'

const AppLayout = () => (
  <div className="fixed-nav-top">
    <Helmet titleTemplate={`%s - ${SITE_NAME}`}
            defaultTitle={SITE_NAME}
    />
    <ProgressBar />
    <header>
      <NavBar />
    </header>
    <main>
      <Routes />
    </main>
    <footer className="center">
       Copyright {new Date().getFullYear()} {COPYRIGHT}
    </footer>
  </div>
)
export default (props) => (
  <Provider store={props.store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <AppLayout />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path of

```
import  { history } from './index'
```

Comment: yes  i change it to props.history in App.js 
but the problem is still here